# Is it 'ok' to disable D's GC?

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, d

I am making an interpreter for a byte-code I created, and it needs to be really fast, for that, I don't want the GC to be a bottleneck, so I disabled it, using `GC.disable();`

But often I read on the internet that D's library requires the GC to be there, but I don't use much of the library, my question is, that if I use the following from the following modules, does it need the GC?:

1. `to` from std.conv
2. `canFind` from std.algorithm
3. `file.read` from std.file
4. `File` from std.stdio

I am using the above functions from mentioned modules in my program, provided that, is it safe to disable the GC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what disabling of the GC does.
Unless you literally compile it out, the GC will always be usable via e.g. new.

Now some basics of how GC's work, when you allocate new memory it has to determine if it can allocate and if it cannot it has to try and cleanup existing memory to be able to allocate. So for D's GC anytime there is an allocation it can go ahead and collect. Now disabling the GC just prevents it for going ahead and doing the collection upon allocation. You can always manually instigate it to do so.

For an interpreter as long as you prevent allocations (reuse memory) you won't need to even disable the GC to prevent it from slowing you down. So remember the rule, "big" allocations and reuse that memory!

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to avoid invoking garbage collection, the trick is to not create any objects for the GC to clean up. Thankfully, D has an attribute that will check at compile-time to make sure you're not accidentally creating any garbage:  @nogc

There's a nice description at: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/functions_more.html

Comment: Walter gave [a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znjesAXEEqw) on writing range-based code that avoids heap allocations.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that you can turn the Garbage Collector back on, let it collect, then turn it back off again, when your interpreter is idle. I use this technique when making games in D. It works perfectly.

```
// Run the GC when we want
core.memory.GC.enable();
core.memory.GC.collect();
core.memory.GC.disable();
```